# Google Drive API : how to connect to "restricted API"?

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I'm trying to connect to the Google Drive V3 API : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
But according to the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth), this API access is "restricted". I want to use this API because this is the only one that allow to "See, edit, create, and delete **all** of your Google Drive files".

Then, it said "If you believe your app requires a restricted scope, refer to [Request restricted scope verification and security assessment](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#assessment)."

After that, I did try to whiteliste my app using the Step2 at [Whitelist connected apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227), with no success :

```
$ curl -d 'client_id=[$CLIENT_ID]' -d 'scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' -d 'response_type=code' 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code'
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

Any advise will be welcome. Or any advise on any other method to list all my files will be welcome too. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it worked but I was using the wrong cURL command. The correct one is :

```
curl ^
--data client_id=%CLIENT_ID% ^
--data client_secret=%CLIENT_SECRET% ^
--data code=%AUTH_CODE% ^
--data redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob ^
--data grant_type=authorization_code ^
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```